# Is there any way to make a UIImage by concatenating other UIImages?

Tags: xcode

I want to make a UIImage that is made from other UIImages, around 10x10 other UIImages, so like a grid. Any way to do this?

Edit 1:
Here's the code I have so far based on lnafziger's link:

```
- (void)displayFullMap
{
NSInteger x, y;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(xMapLength * 64, yMapLength * 64));

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, xMapLength * 64, yMapLength * 64);

UIImage *imageToAdd = [[UIImage alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < xMapLength; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < yMapLength; j++) {
        imageToAdd = some64x64image;
        [imageToAdd drawInRect:rect];
        rect.origin.x += 64;
    }
    rect.origin.x = 0;
    rect.origin.y += 64;
}

UIImage *fullMapImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
fullMapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIImageView *fullMapImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[fullMapImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 480)];
[fullMapImageView setImage:fullMapImage];
[self.view addSubview:fullMapImageView];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

However, no image is being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks right, unless xMapLength or yMapLength are 0 when this function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a blog showing how to merge multiple images:

[www.mindfiresolutions.com](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/iPhoneiPad-Tip-How-to-merge-two-images-into-a-single-image-1604.php)

And here is the code from that page (it could be cleaned up a bit, but it shows you the technique):

```
@implementation LandscapeImage

- (void) createLandscapeImages
{

    CGSize offScreenSize = CGSizeMake(2048, 1380);  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(offScreenSize);

    //Fetch First image and draw in rect
    UIImage* imageLeft = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file1.png"];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 1380);
    [imageLeft drawInRect:rect];  
    [imageLeft release];

    //Fetch second image and draw in rect    
    UIImage* imageRight = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file2.jpg"];
    rect.origin.x += 1024;
    [imageRight drawInRect:rect];    
    [imageRight release];

    UIImage* imagez = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();// it will  returns an image based on the contents of the current bitmap-based graphics context.

    if (imageLeft && imageRight)
    {
        //Write code for save imagez in local cache
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to make a UIImage from another UIImage, but you could add the UIIMages to a UIView, for example, and arrange them in a grid pattern.

Otherwise, I would recommend using Photoshop or other to make your image, and then use that for your UIImageView.